# How do you implement spring boot @Autowired in spring mvc to instantiate MongoRepository interface?

Tags: spring, mongodb, annotations

This is a question for serious "Springers"...

I want to use MongoRepository. So I went to the [spring.io website tutorial for MongoDB CRUD operations](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/);

The first problem is that they are using Spring boot. The second problem is that they are using `@Autowired` on an interface. That annotation seems to be able to create an object (from which methods are called later...)

So.... I'm using regular spring MVC and `@Autowired` doesn;t seem to work there.

How can I "instantiate" that `MongoRepository` interface in my regulart spring mvc without `@Autowired`?

**The MongoRepository extended interface**

```
package hello;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String> {

    public Customer findByFirstName(String firstName);
    public List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);

}
```

**The class containing`@Autowired`**

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        repository.deleteAll();

        // save a couple of customers
        repository.save(new Customer("Alice", "Smith"));
        repository.save(new Customer("Bob", "Smith"));

        // fetch all customers
        System.out.println("Customers found with findAll():");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        for (Customer customer : repository.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }
        System.out.println();

        // fetch an individual customer
        System.out.println("Customer found with findByFirstName('Alice'):");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println(repository.findByFirstName("Alice"));

        System.out.println("Customers found with findByLastName('Smith'):");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        for (Customer customer : repository.findByLastName("Smith")) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should annotate your `Repository` class with `@Repository` and ensure that it's being picked up by Spring's Component scanning. Then you can `@Autowire` it into classes as needed.

To be clear *you* do not "instantiate" the interface. You declare a dependency on an implementation of that interface (via `@Autowired`) and assuming that Spring Data MongDB is on the classpath Spring will create a runtime implementation and make it available as a bean to be injected.

Comment: Also make sure you've properly configured your application context to support Mongo e.g. `@EnableMongoRepositories`.  See documentation at: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb

Comment: Thank you Ben. Also thanks for the github link. Very useful.

Comment: You don't need the `@Repository` only te `@EnableMongoRepositories`.